# looping through a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

my code is

```
acw_user_data={"First Name": First_Name,"Last Name": Last_Name,"Age": Age, "Sex": Sex, "Retired":Retired,
                          "Marital_Status": Marital_Status,"Dependants":Dependants,"Yearly Salary": Yearly_Salary,
                          "Yearly Pension":Yearly_Pension,"Employer Company": Employer_Company,"Distanct Commuted to work":
                            Distance_Commuted_to_work,"Vehicle":Vehicle,"Credit Card": Credit_Card,"Address": Address}

Vehicle = {"Vehicle Make": Vehicle_Make, "Vehicle Model": Vehicle_Model, "Vehicle Year": Vehicle_Year,
                      "Vehicle Type": Vehicle_Type} # inserting key and values for dict. vehicle
            Credit_Card ={"Start Date": Credit_Card_Start_Date, "End Date": Credit_Card_Expire_Date, "Number":Credit_Card_Number, 
                         "Security Code": Credit_Card_CVV,"IBAN": Bank_IBAN } # key and values for dict. Credit card
            Address ={"Main Address": Address_Street, "City": Address_City, 

import datetime
from datetime import date
remove_ccard=[]
def fault_cc(object):
    for Credit_Card in acw_user_data:
        month_diff= int(Credit_Card["End Date"].split("/")[0]) - int(Credit_Card["Start Date"].split("/")[0])
        year_diff = int(Credit_Card["End Date"].split("/")[1]) - int(Credit_Card["Start Date"].split("/")[1])
        if year_diff >= 10:
            remove_ccard.append(year_diff)
            print("Flagged")
remove_ccard
```

i am getting empty list

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible code. And also ask a question please.

Comment: You never call `fault_cc`.

Comment: You're missing closing parentheses in `Vehicle`.

Comment: You didn't actually print the list `remove_ccard` itself, unless you mistakenly tried to call it as a function, which you can't as it's a list.

Comment: There is no list of dictionaries in the code you've shown. The loop you have is over the keys of the `acw_user_data` dictionary, not over some list. Is that not what you intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flaws in your code:

1. Never called method: fault_cc(object)
2. In the line

```
    for Credit_Card in acw_user_data:
        month_diff= int(Credit_Card["End Date"].split("/")[0]) - 
            int(Credit_Card["Start Date"].split("/")[0])
```

when looping over dictionaries, you will get keys.
Learn more about dictionaries in python.[Examples on Dictionaries](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary)

Here is the below corrected code of what I understood :

```
from datetime import datetime 
temp_dict={"First_Name":"n1",
            "End_Date":"2021/01/15",
            "Start_Date":"2009/11/11"
}
temp_dict1={"First_Name":"n2",
            "End_Date":"2022/01/15",
            "Start_Date":"2008/11/11"
}
temp_dict2={"First_Name":"n3",
            "End_Date":"2021/01/15",
            "Start_Date":"2019/01/11"
}
def fault_cc(di):
    li=[]
    start_date=datetime.strptime(di["Start_Date"],"%Y/%m/%d")
    # Converting string date to the datetime format
    end_date=datetime.strptime(di["End_Date"],"%Y/%m/%d")
    year_diff=(end_date.year - start_date.year)
    # For calculating difference of year between 2 date
    if year_diff >=10:
        li.append(di)
    
    return li
    
    
li_di=[temp_dict,temp_dict1,temp_dict2]


for item in li_di:
    print(fault_cc(item))
```

Output of the above code:

```
[{'First_Name': 'n1', 'End_Date': '2021/01/15', 'Start_Date': '2009/11/11'}]
[{'First_Name': 'n2', 'End_Date': '2022/01/15', 'Start_Date': '2008/11/11'}]
[]
```

Hope fully You understand the code.